# add search history from google play to my app in android

Tags: android, search, history, google-play

I am making an app like the Android market where all free app will be available to download, but there will also be a search option for finding the apps on my server.

I wants to show the user a list of searches he has made earlier on Google play or  the Android market. 
Please help me, I can get the history from the browser but I am not able to retrieve it from Google play.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to make yet another app store?

Comment: its my client requirements......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. The Android SDK has no option that allows you to retrieve search history from Google Play, and Google Play does not provide such an option either.